# Detecting Mouse Activities in 30FPS - tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Python's tkinter to create a program that detects Mouse Activities in 30FPS.

This is the code I wrote so far.

```
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime

dtm = 0
touch = False
count = 0

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500+0+0")
root.title("Mouse Activity")

def counter():
   global dtm
   global touch
   global count
   if touch == False:
      dtm = datetime.now().isoformat(sep=' ', timespec='milliseconds')
      RightHand = [[0, dtm]]
      print(RightHand, touch)
      root.after(30, counter)

def handler1(e):
   global dtm
   global touch
   global count
   touch=True
   if(count % 3 == 0):
      dtm = datetime.now().isoformat(sep=' ', timespec='milliseconds')
      RightHand = [[1,dtm]]
      print(RightHand, count)
      count+=1
   else: count+=1
   x = canvas.canvasx(e.x)
   y = canvas.canvasx(e.y)

def handler2(e):
   global dtm
   global touch
   touch = False
   dtm = datetime.now().isoformat(sep=' ', timespec='milliseconds')
   RightHand = [[2, dtm]]
   print(RightHand)
   return counter()

canvas = Canvas(root, bd = 10, highlightthickness=0, width = 500, height = 500, bg = "#ABFFFA")
canvas.pack()

box1 = canvas.create_rectangle(100,100,400,400,fill='white')

counter()

canvas.tag_bind(box1,'<B1-Motion>', handler1)
canvas.tag_bind(box1,'<ButtonRelease-1>', handler2)

b = Thread(target = handler2, args = ())
b.start()

root.mainloop()
```

The code detects the time of Left Mouse Button's Drag Motion and when it was released inside the white box. But it also outputs the time when it was not detecting any mouse activities.

The reason why I'm using `count` in `handler1(e)` is without it the code will detect the activities in a faster FPS.

As I said at the beggining, I want the code to detect Mouse Activities like drag, Left Mouse Button hold in 30FPS.

However The problem is,

1. When doing the Left Mouse Button Drag and stop moving while holding the button, the code stops measuring
   until I release the button.
2. After releasing the Left Mouse Button without moving at all the FPS becomes faster.

it's also showing this error at the beggining.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: handler2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'e'
```

Maybe this could be the problem?

I tried adding `after()` but it gives the `maximum recursion depth` error.
And I tried to solve the error at the beggining, but there's nothing I can do.

I'm still a beginner with Python and I'm also new to these kinds of stuff. So I may not have enough information to know what's wrong and being completly ignorant.

If there's anything missing  please ask me.

Comment: `Thread(target=handler2, args=())` calls `handler2` in a new thread with no arguments. But you defined `def handler2(e):` which takes in 1 argument. Also why do you want your program to run in exactly 30FPS? The easiest way to achieve this is by checking if the function is called before the 33 milliseconds have elapsed, if so, don't do anything.

Comment: This is a proto type code which is going to be a password entering program. And I have another code which is using OpenCV to capture the right hand's coordinates and depth data by using a depth camera running in 30FPS. I was tyring these two to run at the same time so I can get the data as CSV without any lag. But, I have no idea of how to do it I have to separate them. And since the OpenCV is runnning in 30FPS I want to run the Mouse Activity code in 30FPS as well so I don't have to do any complicated calculation. Sorry for the trouble. You think there's a better way to do this?